# CSS textarea image background with opacity without impacting the foreground text

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea that user can change its size.

I need to have an image background for it but I do not want the image disturbs the text so the image should be partially transparent without impacting the opacity of the text that user can type on top of it.

I followed [this link](https://coder-coder.com/background-image-opacity/) which suggests using `::before` but it does not work on my Firefox browser.

```
<textarea class="hero">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
```

CSS

```
.hero {
    position: relative; 
    /* height: 100vh; */
    /* width: 100%; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hero::before {    
      content: "";
      background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/1200/800');
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      opacity: 0.75;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z86yfLvh/1/

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here would be wrapping your `textarea` element into a container, put background on it and tune the background of your `textarea` down, through `background-color` with alpha inside the `rgba()`.

Like this:

```css
.hero {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)
}

.hero-container {  
    background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/1200/800');
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
   <textarea class="hero">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
</div>
```

I should mention also that `::before` won't work with `textarea` because it would have to render it inside the `textarea` which can't contain any HTML elements directly. It's a hard limitation.

---

Alternative solution that also solves another issue that OP mentioned in the comment:

```css
.hero {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
}

.hero-container {  
    background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/1200/800');
    background-size: cover;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
   <textarea class="hero">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</textarea>
</div>
```

I'm using `resize: none` on `textarea` to disable the ability to resize it and I'm adding it to the container instead, while `width: 100%; height: 100%` makes sure `textarea` stretches with the container too.

Comment: This is a great solution. The only problem I have found is that it prevents adjusting `textarea` via `width: 100%`. if giving the same width to the `div` it shows some background of div when shrinking the textarea: https://jsfiddle.net/03fn8b7w/

Comment: Hmm, yes, well, there could be couple ways to try and solve it. Don't use `width` at all on container and force some size on the `textarea` instead, either put pixels there or if you want it to stretch through entire width of your screen, you could put `width: 100vw` but somehow I doubt you want this.

Alternatively, you could always use JS and force those two elements to be the same size. I would need to see a desired outcome to give you @martiz a better potential solution.

Comment: @martiz I actually put more thought to this, check my edit on the post, I gave you an additional solution that potentially solves your new problem too.